# For loop on R - Writing CSV for multiple objects

Tags: r, for-loop

For context, I am running DESEQ2 and want to write CSV result files for different comparisons.

I am trying to create a for loop such that I can create CSV files for the different result files.

My results objects are obtained by the DESEQ2 function: results()

```
A <- results(dds,contrast=c("condition","treatment1","untreated")
B <- results(dds,contrast=c("condition","treatment2","untreated")
C <- results(dds,contrast=c("condition","treatment3","untreated")
D <- results(dds,contrast=c("condition","treatment4","untreated")
```

I would like to get: A.csv, B.csv, C.csv, etc.

My code is as follows:

```
results <- c(A,B,C,D)

for (x in results) {
write.csv(x, file = paste(x,".csv"))
}
```

However, when I run my chunk, it says:

```
Error in for (x in results) { : invalid for() loop sequence
```

Comment: Try `for (x in seq_along(results)) {...`

Comment: Hi Conor, thanks for your help :) Unforuntately, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses a list of string names of the objects to be written. Loop over the list of strings. Use `get()` to get the object from the individual string names. And use `paste0()` to ensure there was not a space in the file name:

```
results <- c("A","B","C","D")

for (x in results) {
  write.csv(get(x), file = paste0(x,".csv"))
}
```

Comment: Hi M.Viking, when I try your code, I'm getting a message: "Error in get(x) : invalid first argument"

Comment: That message means there is not object with that name. Let's troubleshoot. First, comment out the `#write.csv(...` line, and insert `print(x)`. do the string names print properly? Next, test the string names for example, does `head(get("A"))` work? The output should be identical to `head(A)`.